# bash: how to pass variables to a loop within a process substitution

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable, process-substitution, associative-array

How do you pass variable values within a process substitution to a loop within that process substitution?

I'm reading a csv file into an associative array, and while reading each line, I would like to have an `if` loop to test that a particular element in my array is not empty (and do stuff for those):

```
IFS=","
$csvfile="path/to/file.csv"
declare -A arr1  
declare -A arr2  
declare -A arr3 

while read -r -a linedata
do
    arr1["${linedata[1]}"]="${linedata[10]}"
    arr3["${linedata[1]}"]="${linedata[0]}"

    echo repeat -"${linedata[2]}"-

    if [[ -n "${linedata[2]}" ]] && [[ ! "${linedata[2]}" == "" ]] ; then
        arr2["${linedata[2]}"]="${linedata[10]}"
        arr3["${linedata[2]}"]="${linedata[0]}"
    else
        echo skipped for "${linedata[2]}"
    fi
done < $csvfile
```

I see that although the `echo` right before the `if` block prints the value from the `linedata` array correctly, the values in the array do not even seem to get passed through to the `if` condition (the condition is never satisfied, although it should be so that the `else` block is always executed and there the array element value is blank).

I've tried doing `< <($csvfile)` but I got an error about permission denied.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `$csvfile` is undefined.  Can you edit your example to show how `$csvfile` is defined?

Comment: Is the value truly blank or might it just be that an empty value in `${linedata[2]}` is actually a space character?

Comment: Have you considered using `awk` - this seems to be a simpler (and faster) tool for this problem.

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice

Comment: @Jim L., original post edited. @Fiximan, maybe you're right with awk -- just thought having an associative array (need to do some further processing) would make my life easier and I was not quite sure how to do that with awk.

But, I have a fix that got it to work, though I have no clue why it works -- when I pad the quotes with a space when I access the hash array in the `if` condition/block, e .g.  `  "_ ${linedata[2]}_"  ` (the underscore = whitespace), it works! I don't need to do that outside of the `if` block. Very confusing. Would someone elucidate me? Thanks for all the replies.

Comment: @cas, see [SE Comment Link Helper](//stackapps.com/q/2378) which would have helped you rendering that link as [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)